# How to search for a string in columns of a CSV file

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv

I'm trying to create a code that will search for a desired string in the columns of my data frame. For instance, I want to put into a data frame all the companies with "general" in the name and later (separate problem) that begin with a "T". For the first issue, I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
Forbes = pd.read_csv('Forbes2000.csv')
pd.set_option('precision', 2)
Forbes.columns=['#','Rank','Name','Country','Category','Sales','Profits','Assets','Marketvalue',]
for item in lines:
    if 'General' in Forbes["Name"]:
        Forbes.head()
```

This doesn't really return much of anything. I get "NameError: name 'lines' is not defined." I've tried something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
Forbes = pd.read_csv('Forbes2000.csv')
pd.set_option('precision', 2)
Forbes.columns=['#','Rank','Name','Country','Category','Sales','Profits','Assets','Marketvalue',]
Forbes[ Forbes["Name"] == "General"].head()
```

This returns nothing, which I'm lead to believe happens because python is searching for an item in "Name" that is entirely called "General" instead of just searching for its appearance. What can I get to have python print all the companies with "General" in the name, such as "General Motors" or "General Electric" from my list? This is a somewhat separate problem, but from there, how would I print all companies that begin with the letter "T"?

Comment: How abt 'General' in Forbes['Name']

Comment: I have been playing around with this, and I don't think it's doing that's intended. For instance, the following code should print "Yes" six times, as there are six companies with "General" in the name, but instead, nothing is printed. `import pandas as pd \
import csv \
Forbes = pd.read_csv('Forbes2000.csv') #Creates python dataframe \
pd.set_option('precision', 2) \
Forbes.columns=['#','Rank','Name','Country','Category','Sales','Profits','Assets','Marketvalue',] \
if 'General' in Forbes['Name']: \
    print("Yes")`

Comment: Your first snippet isn't working because you're iterating over a variable `lines` which you never defined (i.e it doesn't exist). It's in the error message. I wouldn't assign to `.columns`. Also, explicit iteration should really be a last resort when working with Pandas. Finally, the snippet you shared in your comment above doesn't work because `if 'General' in Forbes['Name']:` only checks if the Series `Forbes['Name']` contains the element `General`, and nothing else. I **strongly** recommend reading the Pandas docs to familiarize yourself with the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['General motor','abc','General Electric','xyz'], columns = ['name'])

df[df['name'].str.contains('General')]
#op
    name
 0  General motor
 2  General Electric
```

Comment: This was the solution I was looking for. Worked wonderfully. Thanks so much!

Comment: u r welcome, if it has help,  u can accept the answer